# Xamarin Cross Platform disable IOS

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I'm new to **Xamarin**.

My goal is to develop an app for both **Android** and **Windows phone** platforms, **without IOS**. I dont have any mac to test.

Under the properties solution, I already tried to remove IOS from the targets platform, but doesn't allow me. It's mentioned that its

Thats the solution i tried withou sucess:
[Remove ios, windows8, and wp8 from Xamarin Forms PCL - nuget 3.0 opt-into error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041291/remove-ios-windows8-and-wp8-from-xamarin-forms-pcl-nuget-3-0-opt-into-error)

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter! It doesn't mean you are actually stuck with iOS in any way.

The only thing it means is that the set you have selected is also compatible with the libraries in Xamarin.iOS. So it means that you *could* create an iOS project without too much trouble if you would want to in the future.

If you do not create an iOS project, you won't get an iOS app.