# WCF issues in Xamarin

Tags: wcf, xamarin

I am trying to generate `WCF Services` Xamarin Cross platform ( PCL ) project based on the sample giving by xamarin itself i.e. [TodoWCF](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoWCF/)

I found few issues wile generating `WCF Services` in xamarin using `VS2015`

1) I don't see  `Add service` option to add `WSDL` file

to resolve this i found this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041291/remove-ios-windows8-and-wp8-from-xamarin-forms-pcl-nuget-3-0-opt-into-error) and i tried to remove `windows phone 8.1` after removing `Xamarin.Forms` and adding it again.

[image]

2) After that i tried to tap on `Add Services` and entered the WSDL

but VS2015 is constantly getting restarted when it tries to generate code for 
service endpoint.

3) I dont see any of the dependency added in `TodoWFC` sample provided by xamarin itself in my project

[image]

and really dont know how did they manage to generate WCF code inside it.

I read [WCF Walkthrough in Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/)  and [Consuming WCF in Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/wcf/) but no where they have specified how to add WCF Service and System.ServiceModel dependencies.

hence i fill this topics are still not resolved

Answer (score 0):

From the updates of Xamarin and .Net Framework it is not possible to add the service references as WCF from the solution explorer, you can verify this post where they proposed how to solve it

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2464#event-1474936235

If you are still using PCL, it is possible to change the ProfileTarget, you can see this post

https://luisdavidxamshap.wordpress.com/2018/01/26/consumir-web-service-wcf-con-xamarin-forms-pcl-paso-a-paso/

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [Linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)), we prefer answer that provide at least a solid summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information. [More info on link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).