# Newly created Xamarin Forms PCL project contains errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Using Visual Studio 2017 I create a new project of type "Cross Platform App (Xamarin Forms or Native)".  I select '.NET Framework 4.5' and PCL as the Code Sharing Strategy.  When the App is created, there is a reference to the PCL in the Android project.  However, this shows a yellow triangle indicating an error. There are no other compilation errors.

If I remove the reference and try to re-add it I get the error `"Unable to add a reference to project '<PclProjectName>'. The current project's target is not one of or compatible with the targets of Portable Library project '<PclProjectName>'."`

If I try to follow the advice to change the PCL targets, I run into the problems described in [Remove ios, windows8, and wp8 from Xamarin Forms PCL - nuget 3.0 opt-into error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041291/remove-ios-windows8-and-wp8-from-xamarin-forms-pcl-nuget-3-0-opt-into-error)

Does this new project template work for others, and if so what do I need to do to my system to correct any problems?

Comment: What's the version of your XF? Do you mean by using the default template, the reference to PCL has problem in android client project?

Comment: XF 2.3.3.193.  Yes I mean what you describe.