# Xamarin Forms I have used SQLite Now I want to use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

Tags: xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I have A project in Xamarin Form and i'm Using Sqlite Database in it and Now i want to convert this Sqlite to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` but i i found this Exception.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression 
State
Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 3.0.0-preview6.19304.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

i have 3 project in my project that target .NET FrameWork 4.5 but `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` Require **.NET Standered 2.0** .I stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [convert your PCL project to .Net Standard project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/net-standard) in order to use Entity framework Core.

Comment: I want to Convert .NET Standered to .NET Core and Use EntityFrameWork.SQLite

Comment: This [adapted Xamarin.Forms Todo Sample](https://github.com/cwrea/XamarinTodo/tree/NETStd20_EFCore203) use Entity Framework Core for accessing SQLite and is a .NET Standard 2.0 project.

Comment: One other thing i want to tell you that i have existing project that is completed in .Net Stander with Sqlite Now i want to Convert .NET Core with  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

Comment: I Want to Upgrade .Net Standered to .NET Core to Existing PRoject

Comment: [How is .NET Standard different from .NET Core?](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-is-net-standard-different-from-net-core): ".NET Standard is a specification", ".NET Core is a concrete .NET platform and implements the .NET Standard."

Comment: I'm Confused Actually i want to Use EntityFramework sqlite core insted Sqlite. When i,M Installing EntityFrameWork Then Above Exception Come and failed to install EntityFrameWork Sqlite Core

Comment: Im Facing This Problem to changing the target Framework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041291/remove-ios-windows8-and-wp8-from-xamarin-forms-pcl-nuget-3-0-opt-into-error